# Firebase phone authenticatication error on production

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, sha1

I am working on an app that uses firebase phone authentication (authUI) to sign in users. I have integrated firebase successfully in multiple apps before without any error. For this app I get the error on[image: the screenshot]. This is very annoying since the app does not produce the same error on debug. I noticed the error when I uploaded the apk to playstore and my users started complaining. I have double checked everything. I even used the firebase plugin to import firebase to the project. Everything on google-services.json is okay even SHA1 matches. Anybody experienced the same and maybe anyone who know how to solve it?? Frustrating

Comment: Add SHA1 of your release key store which you have used to sign the app.

Comment: Hey @android_hub. Thanks for the answer can you explain some more. If possible can you help me generate the key (how do I generate it ) I know how to add SHA 1 from the signing report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **Release Keystore SHA1** to your Firebase project just as you did add Debug SHA1

You can obtain the key

> keytool -list -v -keystore **[release_key_path_here]**

Copy the certificate fingerprint SHA1

Follow detail steps [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/)

Comment: Dude you saved my day. You are the best. Thank you